# Update CakePhp View each time a record is inserted in the db table

Tags: javascript, jquery, cakephp, websocket, phpwebsocket

Am making an application that will enable remote viewing of records and reports via a browser. I have used cakePHP to make the application and its working fine,but i have one little problem,since the application does not do any inserts its just reading the data,i want when a user has opened a view and a record has been inserted on the table,it should update all open clients, instead of the user refreshing the page to get the new records.
Is there a cakePHP websocket plugin that actually works? 
Our webhost doesnt allow installing programs or adding apache modules so nodejs or similar solutions wont be applicable here.

> Am looking for a purely php and javascript implementation where you
>   just upload your application files to the webserver and everything
>   runs. You dont have to run, install extras or do any configuration on apache or stuff... afteruploading your files

here is a function in one of my controllers(BooksController.php) that retrieves the data to the view

```
public function list_books()
  {
    $this->Books->recursive = 0;
    $this->paginate = array('order' => array('Serial_No' => 'DESC'));
    $this->set('All_Books', $this->paginate());
  }
```

and here is one of my views(list_books.ctp) that displays the data in a table paginated.

```
<div class="row-fluid">

    <div class="span12">
        <?php echo $this->Session->flash() ?>   
        <h4><?php echo __('All Books') ?></h4>
        <hr>               
                    <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>    <th><?php echo __('Serial No') ?></th>
                    <th><?php echo __('Title') ?></th>
                                        <th><?php echo __('Author') ?></th>
                                        <th><?php echo __('Publisher') ?></th>
                                        <th><?php echo __('Category') ?></th>
                                        <th><?php echo __('Section') ?></th>
                                        <th><?php echo __('Available') ?></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php foreach( $All_Books as $book ){ ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $this->Html->link(__($book['Book']['Serial_No']),'/books/view/'.$book['Book']['Serial_No']) ?></td>                                         
                                        <td><?php echo $book['Book']['Title'] ?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo $book['Book']['Author'] ?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo $book['Book']['Publisher'] ?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo $book['Book']['Category'] ?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo $book['Book']['Section'] ?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo $book['Book']['Available'] ?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php } ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
                <?php echo $this->Paginator->prev('« Previous', null, null, array('class' => 'disabled'));            
echo $this->Paginator->numbers();
echo $this->Paginator->next('Next »', null, null, array('class' => 'disabled'));
echo $this->Paginator->counter(array(
    'format' => 'Page {:page} of {:pages}, showing {:current} records out of
             {:count} total, starting on record {:start}, ending on {:end}'
));
 ?>
    </div>

</div>
```

What can i add on my view or controller or model, to make the view auto updating?
Can this be achieved using ajax?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an AJAX poller, or (HTML5) websockets (using [Pusher](http://pusher.com/) for instance) for push notification.

Answer (score 0):

You've already mentioned it, AJAX. That's the easiest way to accomplish something like that, simply do a check in the background via AJAX, and if necessary reload the page, or update only the affected parts by again using an AJAX request.

Depending on the amount of data you could of course simply load the data directly instead of checking for updates first.

**Update** I've misunderstood the question, in case the inserts/udpates are made from an external source that you have no direct control over as described in the comments, the only options I could think of for checking whether updating the view is necessary, would be checking the `UPDATE_TIME` [information schema](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/tables-table.html) (works on MyISAM only), using [triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html) for updating a custom information schema that could be checked, or counting the rows, however the latter would only cover inserts.

All methods would fetch the comparison value (update time or row count) in the controller action of the specific view, and pass that value to the view where it's then used in the AJAX call. The AJAX call invokes a controller method where the passed value is compared to the current time/count value in order to determine whether an update is necessary.

Please note that the examples are untested!

## Information Schema

The easiest method would be checking the `UPDATE_TIME` information schema, however as mentioned this only works for MyISAM tables:

**Model:**

```
public function getUpdateTime()
{   
    $db = $this->getDataSource();
    
    $result = $db->fetchAll('
        SELECT
            UNIX_TIMESTAMP(UPDATE_TIME) AS update_time
        FROM
            information_schema.tables
        WHERE
            TABLE_SCHEMA = ?
            AND
            TABLE_NAME = ?',
            
        array
        (
            $db->config['database'],
            $this->table
        )
    );
    
    if(empty($result) || !isset($result[0][0]['update_time']))
    {
        return false;
    }
    
    return (int)$result[0][0]['update_time'];
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public function list_books()
{
    $this->set('lastUpdate', $this->Books->getUpdateTime());
    
    $this->Books->recursive = 0;
    $this->paginate = array('order' => array('Serial_No' => 'DESC'));
    $this->set('All_Books', $this->paginate());
}

public function checkForUpdate($time)
{
    $updateNecessary = $this->Books->getUpdateTime() > (int)$time;
    return new CakeResponse(array('body' => json_encode($updateNecessary)));
}
```

**View:**

```
<script>
jQuery(function($)
{
    var lastUpdate = <?php echo $lastUpdate; ?>;
    
    function checkForUpdate()
    {
        $.get('/books/checkForUpdate', {time: lastUpdate}, function(updateNecessary)
        {
            if(updateNecessary === true)
            {
                alert('update necessary');
                // now reload the page or use an additional AJAX request for updating the content
            }
            else
            {
                queueUpdateCheck();
            }
        },
        'json');
    }
    
    function queueUpdateCheck()
    {
        setTimeout(checkForUpdate, 5000);
    }
    
    queueUpdateCheck();
});
</script>
```

---

## Using Triggers

Another option would be using [triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html). You'd need an additional table that connects tables and time values using for example the table name, and two triggers, one for inserts, one for updates. These triggers could then update the custom information table.

**Information Table**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table_stats` (
  `table_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `update_time` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`table_name`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `table_stats` (`table_name`, `update_time`)
VALUES ('books', NOW());
```

**Triggers**

```
CREATE TRIGGER `update_time_after_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `books`
    FOR EACH ROW 
        UPDATE `table_stats` SET `update_time` = NOW() WHERE `table_name` = 'books';

CREATE TRIGGER `update_time_after_update` AFTER UPDATE ON `books`
    FOR EACH ROW 
        UPDATE `table_stats` SET `update_time` = NOW() WHERE `table_name` = 'books';
```

**Model:**

```
public function getUpdateTime()
{   
    $db = $this->getDataSource();
    
    $result = $db->fetchAll('
        SELECT
            UNIX_TIMESTAMP(update_time) AS update_time
        FROM
            `table_stats`
        WHERE
            `table_name` = ?',
            
        array
        (
            $this->table
        )
    );
    
    if(empty($result) || !isset($result[0][0]['update_time']))
    {
        return false;
    }
    
    return (int)$result[0][0]['update_time'];
}
```

**Controller** and **View** would be the same as in the previous example.

---

## Counting rows

Now the last option would be comparing the row count, which would of course only work for inserts. In this example the **Model** would stay untouched.

**Controller:**

```
public function list_books()
{
    $this->set('rowCount', $this->Books->find('count'));
    
    $this->Books->recursive = 0;
    $this->paginate = array('order' => array('Serial_No' => 'DESC'));
    $this->set('All_Books', $this->paginate());
}

public function checkForUpdate($rowCount)
{
    $updateNecessary = $this->Books->find('count') != (int)$rowCount;
    return new CakeResponse(array('body' => json_encode($updateNecessary)));
}
```

**View:**

```
<script>
jQuery(function($)
{
    var rowCount = <?php echo $rowCount; ?>;
    
    function checkForUpdate()
    {
        $.get('/books/checkForUpdate', {rowCount: rowCount}, function(updateNecessary)
        {
            if(updateNecessary === true)
            {
                alert('update necessary');
                // now reload the page or use an additional AJAX request for updating the content
            }
            else
            {
                queueUpdateCheck();
            }
        },
        'json');
    }
    
    function queueUpdateCheck()
    {
        setTimeout(checkForUpdate, 5000);
    }
    
    queueUpdateCheck();
});
</script>
```

---

## Retrieving data together with the update check

Of course you could also submit possible data together with the update check, in order to avoid additional requests. For example:

**Model**

```
public function checkForUpdate($time)
{
    $data = '';
    
    $updateAvailable = $this->Books->getUpdateTime() > (int)$time;
    if($updateAvailable)
    {
        $this->set('books', $this->Books->find('all'));
        
        // render /Elements/books.ctp in ajax.ctp layout and grab the rendered content
        $this->viewPath = 'Elements';
        $view = $this->render('books', 'ajax');
        $data = $view->body();
    }
    
    $body = compact('updateAvailable', 'data');

    return new CakeResponse(array('body' => json_encode($body)));
}
```

**View**

```
<script>
jQuery(function($)
{
    var lastUpdate = <?php echo $lastUpdate; ?>;

    function checkForUpdate()
    {
        $.get('/books/checkForUpdate', {time: lastUpdate}, function(response)
        {
            if(response.updateAvailable === true)
            {
                // the data is already available, so directly update the content
                $('#content').html(response.data);
            }
            
            queueUpdateCheck();
        },
        'json');
    }

    function queueUpdateCheck()
    {
        setTimeout(checkForUpdate, 5000);
    }

    queueUpdateCheck();
});
</script>
```

Comment: I am not doing any update or inserts from cakephp(the web app) so will this still work?
"Cache::write('model_last_update_books', time());"

Comment: Sorry, I've misunderstood your question. No, in that case this won't work since the `afterSave` callback is triggered on model save only. Do you have any influence on the application that makes the actual inserts/updates? ie, could you for example make it insert/update additional data, or if its running on the same server, write data to the filesystem? If not, do the inserts/updates maybe include creation/modification dates?

Comment: I dont have any access to that system and its a desktop app an different user's pc's and the server on our app server but it doesnt save modification dates& time on all tables and most of the data we need is in tables that dont have the date& time of modification

Comment: I see... which DBMS (version and storage engine) are you using? And is this a fixed requirement, or do you want to support different DBMS?

Comment: We are using Mysql and both innodb and myisam tables. We cant change because the desktop system cant support another dbms.

Comment: Ok, there is an fairly easy way for MyISAM tables, but not for InnoDB. I'll update my answer with examples for both, MyISAM and InnoDB.

Comment: Well, check what's going on in the DB, try whether the triggers actually work at all by manually issuing appropriate SQL `INSERT/UPDATE` queries. And remove the triggers to check whether they are actually causing the problem. Anyways, not being able to get triggers working would be something for a new question where you could provide appropriate information (version numbers, code, debugging results, etc).

Comment: i have tried your method,i was able to create the triggers. I get the error Undefined variable: lastUpdate ,do we need to initialze this variable? and i also dont see where its getting a value

Comment: The variable is set in the `list_books()` method so that it can be used in the `list_books.ctp` view: `$this->set('lastUpdate', ...);`