# Cakephp live stream/feed

Tags: php, ajax, cakephp, timeline

I am trying to build an application that has a live stream/feed of comments.

Basically I have a topic which has many comments. Comments also have many likes (in the form of a pretty heart hehe). The feed of comments could be over 1000 and at the moment I am using AJAX to grab all comments (new and old) and then reloading them into a specific div in the page. This process is done even 5000ms and works ok atm as the whole page doesn't refresh and a user can continue to type a comment without losing their data.

Using the answers here (specifically from the user NDM i would be able to check the DB for changes and populate only those new comments [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17906697/update-cakephp-view-each-time-a-record-is-inserted-in-the-db-table)!

Here is my problem... This loads new comments nicely but will not populate the changes to the likes/dislikes to existing comments in the view.

What is the best approach for me here so that new comments are added but changes to the comments are also updated if required?

Kind regards,
KM

Answer (score 2):

My best idea, is a mix of a client side application(javascript) that will use a thin data structure(json with changes only), that will manipulate the existing view.

each record (comment) will be signed after every change (unixtime will do the trick), and only changed comments (and their likes) will be sent back to the client.